# PHP - Output is adding "<br />"... Braindead

Tags: php, line, line-breaks

So I'm banging my head against this... I'm not too experienced with PHP as of yet, someone asked me to edit a WP plugin.

**The PHP**

```
foreach ($options['forms'][$form_id]['inputs'] as $id => $input) {
        if (!$input['show'])
            continue;
        $val    = '';
        if (isset($_POST[$id])){
            $val    = esc_attr(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST[$id])));
        }else{
            if( isset($input['value']) ) $val   = esc_attr(strip_tags(stripslashes($input['value'])));
        }

        $error  = ' ';
        if (isset($input['error']) && $input['error']) 
            $error  = ' error ';
        if($input['type'] != 'hidden')
            $content .= "\t".'<div class="sf_input_container_byben"><label class="w2llabel'.$error.$input['type'].'" for="sf_'.$id.'">'.esc_html(stripslashes($input['label'])).':';

        if ($input['required'] && $input['type'] != 'hidden')
            $content .= ' *';

        if($input['type'] != 'hidden')
            $content .= '</label>';

        if ($input['type'] == 'text') {         
            $content .= '<input value="'.$val.'" id="sf_'.$id.'" class="w2linput text" name="'.$id.'" type="text"/></div>';
        } else if ($input['type'] == 'textarea') {
            $content .= '<textarea id="sf_'.$id.'" class="w2linput textarea" name="'.$id.'">'.$val.'</textarea></div>';
        } else if ($input['type'] == 'hidden') {
            $content .= '<input type="hidden" id="sf_'.$id.'" class="w2linput hidden" name="'.$id.'" value="'.$val.'"></div>';
        }
    }
```

Obviously that's partial.

Everything is outputting as expected, *except* for the fact that I'm getting a `<br />` after each `</label>` (closing tag). nl2br is NOT in use anywhere in the php file.

What am I missing? I can link to the files directly if more information is needed.

**The HTML is being output as:**

```
<div class="sf_input_container_byben">
    <label class="w2llabel text" for="sf_first_name">First name: *</label><br />
    <input value="" id="sf_first_name" class="w2linput text" name="first_name" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the CSS code for `class="w2llabel'`

Comment: P.S. It looks like you're not sanitizing `$input['type']` in `<label class="w2llabel'.$error.$input['type'].'" for="sf_'.$id.'">'`. Possibly `$id` as well.

Comment: Nothing in the CSS for `class="w2llabel"` that would be causing the issue. It sets the display as table-cell, sets a width, and adds padding.

Comment: Something tells me `esc_html()` is the culprit. Can you show what this function does?

Comment: Does your page output *look like* it has a line-break (`<br/>`), or does it *actually* have a line-break? For example, `<div>`s are display-block. Would posting HTML source be possible?

Comment: Grzegorz: That's what I'm thinking. As I mentioned I'm merely editing Salesforce's WP Plugin, I haven't dabbled in WP's PHP enough to know exactly what esc_html is doing. EthanB: It _actually_ writes a line break in the HTML.

Comment: I did a google search and found a few posts about this. Here is one.... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unwanted-line-break-inserted-after-a-label-tag

Comment: @Paul that link is in regards to editing via the WYSIWYG editor; my issue is occurring from code. Although I didn't think to disable `br` elements via CSS... be right back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an optimal fix, but I'm running out of time so I just used `display: none;` in my CSS to hide `<br>` elements within the form.

Props to Paul for linking me to a forum thread that was covering a separate issue but provided that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can fix this in CSS by doing this:

```
label{display: inline;}
```

It seems like the label is acting like a block element, so changing it to inline, or inline-block even, it should stop adding an extra line at the end. Beware that you could already have code that causes the label to display as block, so search for it in css files first.

Comment: I mentioned CSS, not PHP. If there is CSS with label{display: block;} this is the fix. Nothing to do with PHP.